# How to use custom location or path instead root for several apps using nginx?

Tags: html, node.js, nginx, web

### Problem

I have a web which works fine on a root domain like `mydomain.com` without any modification. But if I want to serve it as `mydomain.com/app1` I I need to modify the source code in the backend and statics links (css, images, etc) in the html

- nodejs :

  - from `app.get('/')`  to `app.get('/app1')`
- html

  - from `src="main.css"` to `src="app1/main.css"`

### Question

Should I always modify the application when I want to assign a **domain/path** using nginx?

### Sample app

https://github.com/jrichardsz/nodejs-static-pages/blob/master/server.js

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    // ejs render automatically looks in the views folder
    res.render('index');
});
```

### Nginx for root domain

This is my nginx configuration which works for **mydomain.com**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;
 
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
  }
}
```

### Attempt for **mydomain.com/app1**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com;
  
  location /app1/ { 
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/app1/; 
  }
}
```

And this is the fix in node js app

```
app.get('/app1', function(req, res) {
    // ejs render automatically looks in the views folder
    res.render('index');
});
```

I tried :

https://github.com/expressjs/express-namespace

http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html

But in both cases, I need change my node js app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should you always modify the application when you want to assign a domain/path?

No, you shouldn't have to modify the application at all.

When you use `proxy_pass` in this manner, you need to rewrite the URL with regex.  Try something like this:

```
  location ~ ^/app1/(.*)$ { 
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/$1$is_args$args; 
  }
```

See also:  https://serverfault.com/q/562756/52951

Comment: Thanks Brad. In my case I change localhost to 127.0.0.1 and works with your example. I have another question related to this requirement but with "redirects". Thanks so much!!