# How to allow multiple external domains to access data from single application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, cross-domain

I have a web application created using Spring Boot. Multiple users (like Company1, Company2, Company3) are registered in this application and they all have their own data. Consider that this application is hosted at `www.myapp.com`. Now these companies want to access their personal data but from their own domain. Like Company1 wants to access their data from `www.company1.com/data`, Company2 wants to access theirs from `www.company2.org/info`, and Company3 wants to access theirs from `www.company3.edu`. Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: Do you mean that the companies are already using those domains for their own web applications or can you map those domains to your 'www.myapp.com' server?

Comment: #1 Do you need just have several domains for the same application? #2 Applications naturally works very well in a domain or subdomain like kshitij.com or kshitij.company1.com. If you need a custom context like www.company1.com/data , you need to refactor your web application  to allow use custom context or url instead simple domain. And if your app has complex redirect you will cry. Please convince to your client to use domain or subdomain instead /data or /info.#3 Finally this is a job for http routes like nginx/haproxy not for application. In the next comment I will share you reference links

Comment: #1 [complex redirects for /context instead domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57503924/using-relative-redirect-in-spring-boot-fails) #2 [same app with several domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40985784/nginx-multiple-node-js-applications-on-same-server-using-domain-path) #3 [nginx configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54095059/3957754)

Comment: Confirm your final scenario and I help you with nginx configurations